# Binary tree with alternating sign

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

Given a Binary tree with the following property that all of it's leaf nodes are at positive(+) sign then sign alternates upto root for that path. So a node can have multiple sign depending upon the path.

Now we need to find out the sum of each path and the whole sum of tree.
[image]

```
for ex:
there are 5 paths in the given binary tree.

path 1: 10-2+3-4 = 7

path 2: 19-8+2-3+4 = 14

path 3: 12-11+17-3+4 = 19

path 4: 2-9+1-4 = -10

path 5: 21-9+1-4 = 9


overall sum 39
```

The problem here is to decide the sign of each node which is governed by the leaf node in it's underlying path.

I can think of a solution with O(n) time complexity and O(n) space where i could save each path in vector traversing from root to bottom & then deciding sign of each node starting from leaf node, thereby calculating sum of each path.

Now can anybody suggest any improved method, with O(1) space complexity.
Any of the recursive or iterative method will be preferred.

I hope that i had clearly explained the Question. Still, if any doubt arises, I would soon add more details.

**EDIT: binary tree is stored & implemented like this & not in an array**

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct node* newNode(int data)

{
  struct node* node = (struct node*)
                       malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node->data = data;
  node->left = NULL;
  node->right = NULL;

  return(node);
}

int main()
{
  struct node *root = newNode(1);
  root->left        = newNode(2);
  root->right       = newNode(3);
  root->left->left  = newNode(4);
  root->left->right = newNode(5); 
}
```

The space required to store the tree cannot be saved in any case. please do not go into making the tree. Assume that you are given the root node of a tree, with tree already built.

**I am saying about the extra space required to run a specific algorithm to answer the question.**

Comment: do you need to maximize sum? Couldn't understand the criteria for deciding sign of non-leaf node.

Comment: No, we don't need to maximise sum.
Criteria is simple: leaf nodes are at positive sign & then sign alternates upto root for that path.
So a node can have multiple sign depending upon the path

Comment: What do you mean by O(1), you will have to go through the nodes atleast once

Comment: could you explain how you plan to do it in O(n) time and space ?

Comment: @sasha: I am talking about O(1) space not O(1) Time
O(1) space means not using any extra space.
And I would do it by using a path array path[] to store current root to leaf path. Traverse from root to all leaves in top-down fashion. While traversing, store data of all nodes in current path in array path[]. When we reach a leaf node, we can stop.

Comment: @sanjayk79 Am I clear on this now?

Comment: So you want an O(1) space and O(any) time complexity?

Comment: @PhamTrung  obviously better would be preferred
but yes right now O(any)
because i am not getting any way to deal with this question with O(1) space

Comment: Hmm, quite difficult, because you already need O(n) space to store the whole tree, so O(1) seems impossible :)

Comment: you are getting it all wrong, the space required to store the tree cannot be saved in any case.
please do not go into making the the tree.
assume that you are given the root node of a tree, with tree already built.
I am saying about the extra space required to run a specific algorithm to answer the question. As it was in my suggested solution where i am using an extra vector of size n to store the node values(plus the space required to built the tree)

Comment: @Prashant Space complexity is to talk about the space using of the whole program, not just part of it. Anyway, you should put this as part of your question.

Comment: Do you have control over the tree implementation? I can think of an algorithm with O(n) time and O(1) space complexity if the tree is a complete binary tree stored in an array.

Comment: Well it would just be Pham Trung's algorithm but you could calculate the parent node index instead of needing a reference to the parent.

Comment: @PhamTrung: sure I've put that as part of my question.

Comment: @ElliotHatch: I've also added the details about the implementation of tree.

Comment: @Prashant so, we cannot add a link back from child to its parent node? :(

Comment: @PhamTrung Obviously not, otherwise it would have been damn easy problem.

Comment: we don't have parent pointer

Comment: Can we change value of node in the tree?

Comment: You can, How will that affect anything , obviously you can change

Comment: Updated my answer, if we can modify the node in the tree, so we can use left node as a link back to its parent, which solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, we can easily obtain an solution with O(1) extra space and O(n^2) time complexity if we **can** traverse the tree from bottom to top:

```
for(every leaf in tree){

   Node node = leaf;
   int total = 0;
   int sign = 1;
   while(node != null){
       total += sign*node.value;
       node = node.parent;
       sign *= -1; 
   }
   print total;
}
```

For top to bottom traversal with O(n) time complexity, to obtain O(1) extra space, a more complex algorithm is required

```
Node node = root;
Node last = null;
int total = 0;
int sign = 1;
boolean back = false;
while(node != null){
     total += sign*node.value;
     if(node is leaf){
        if(sign == 1)
           print total;//Need to check if sign is not positive
        else
           print -total;
        back = true;//If this is leaf, we need to go back
        total -= sign*node.value;
        last = node;
        node = node.parent;
     }else if(back){
        if(last is left child){
           back = false;
           node = node.rightChild;
        }else{//We need to continue to go back if we are going back and this is right child 
           last = node;
           total -= sign*node.value;
           node = node.parent;
        } 
     }else{
        total += sign*node.value;
        node = node.leftChild;
     }
     sign *= -1; 

}
```

**Note**:

- A recursive top to bottom traversal or iterative traversal using a stack will easily create an O(n) space complexity, so be careful!
- Without the parent link in each Node, we cannot solve this problem, as in that case, a stack-like data structure is needed to traverse the tree.

**Update:**

As we can change value of node in the tree, so we can modify the left link of a node to use it as a link to parent node.

```
Node node = root;
Node last = null;
int total = 0;
int sign = 1;
boolean back = false;
while(node != null){
     total += sign*node.value;
     if(node is leaf){
        if(sign == 1)
           print total;//Need to check if sign is not positive
        else
           print -total;
        back = true;//If this is leaf, we need to go back
        total -= sign*node.value;
        Node tmp = last;//For leaf node, we can just use variable last
        last = node;
        node = tmp;
     }else if(back){
        if(last is not right child){
           back = false;
           last = node;
           node = node.rightChild;
        }else{//We need to continue to go back if we are going back and this is right child 
           last = node;
           total -= sign*node.value;
           node = node.leftChild;
        } 
     }else{
        total += sign*node.value;
        Node tmp = node.leftChild;
        node.leftChild = last;
        last = node;
        node = tmp;
     }
     sign *= -1; 

}
```